# How to use drag and drop to design the side menu, if the cursor has pointed, the tree list appears?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jmenu

I would like to design side bar some thing like below , by using drag and drop to design the side menu, if the cursor has pointed on it, the tree list appears from this menu.

[image]

When cursor has pointed on "projects"in the LH, the tree list in RH appear.

Comment: Thank you, it's work, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, it seems a [`JTabbedPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) (appropriately configured to show the tabs down the side) is the way to implement this.